# How detrend a line if i know the slope?

Tags: regression, anomaly-detection

I am using linear regression to get the slope of some data. If i know the slope how can i flatten the line so that it has no slope?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a $y$ variable predicted by $x$ and want to fit a model $y = a + bx$ but know $b$?

Comment: Set $\beta_i=0$?

Comment: What would be your reason for 'detrending'?

Comment: 1. Do you *know* the slope (as per title) or are you estimating it (as per body text)? 2. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dataset $y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$ and you use linear regression to obtain the least square estimate $\hat{\beta}$, your fitted values are $\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}x_i$. Therefore, you detrend your dataset by calculating the difference $y_i - \hat{y}_i$.

Here an R example:

```
## generate a dataset and plot it
x = 1:20                 # predictor variable
y = 0.5*x + rnorm(length(x), 0,1) # response variable = slope + noise
plot(x,y)                # plot data

## now fit the data
df     = data.frame(x,y) # generate a dataframe
fit.lm = lm(y~x, df)     # linear regression
summary(fit.lm)          # display result of lin. reg. => get estimator of the slope

## Obtain the residual of the fit = retreaded data
yHat    = fitted(fit.lm) # get the fitted values
epsilon = y - yHat       # one way to obtain residuals

## There exists more direct ways to obtain the residual:
resid(fit.lm)            # second way to obtain residuals
fit.lm$residuals         # third way
```

Comment: OP said "If i know the slope". So I think you do not need to estimate the slope. Also your model does not have intercept, but your fitted model has intercept.

Comment: This depends on the meaning of "knowing". The OP starts the question with "I am using linear regression to get the slope of some data." Therefore, I reckon that the fit is the source of knowledge. If this is not the case my answer is probably false anyway and I am going to delete it.

Comment: That is the reason I voted to close, because I really cannot figure out what is asked for.